# Returning value of the key in AsyncStorage (getItem) instead of a promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, asyncstorage

I want to use a value stored in the AsyncStorage in another function.

Here's my ValueHandler.js

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export async function getSavedValue() {
  try {
    const val = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyStore:savedValue');
    console.log("#getSavedValue", val);
    return val;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("#getSavedValue", error);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I made the above function getSavedValue() to get the value of the savedValue stored in the AsyncStorage.

```
import {getSavedValue} from '../lib/ValueHandler';
import Api from '../lib/Api';

export function fetchData() {
  return(dispatch, getState) => {
    var params = [
      'client_id=1234567890',
    ];
    console.log("#getSavedValue()", getSavedValue());
    if(getSavedValue() != null) {
      params = [
        ...params,
        'savedValue='+getSavedValue()
      ];
    }
    params = params.join('&');
    console.log(params);
    return Api.get(`/posts/5132?${params}`).then(resp => {
      console.log(resp.posts);
      dispatch(setFetchedPosts({ post: resp.posts }));
    }).catch( (ex) => {
      console.log(ex);
    });
  }
}
```

How do I achieve this? I really wanted a simple method to save a value in the local storage and retrieve it simply when I need to make an API call.

Anyone got any suggestions or solutions to this?

Comment: I have posted an answer assuming the issue is that fetch call is made before the key(saved value in asyncStorage) is retrieved(retrieving from asyncStorage is async). Plz correct me if the issue is something else because it isn't well explained in the question :)

Comment: async functions return a Promise ... that's what async/await is, sugar for promises ... to get the value, you'll have to `var value = await getSavedValue()` - or, since the function calling getSavedValue isn't `async` ... you'll ned old school promise syntax, `getSavedValue().then(value => /* use value here and here only */)`

Comment: @JaromandaX- I get it. I know the conventional way of using it within the then() part, I just wanted a direct way of saving it as a value and accessing it directly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you can't make asynchronous into synchronous - never possible, a moments thought would make you realise that

Comment: Yeah, but I wished there was a sync function to access the storage in the first place or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export async function getSavedValue() {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => { 
      try {
        const val = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyStore:savedValue');
        console.log("#getSavedValue", val);
        resolve(val);
      }catch (error) {
        console.log("#getSavedValue", error);
        reject(error)
      }  
   })
}


import {getSavedValue} from '../lib/ValueHandler';
import Api from '../lib/Api';

export function fetchData() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    var params = [
      'client_id=1234567890',
    ];
    console.log("#getSavedValue()", getSavedValue());
    if(getSavedValue() != null) {
      params = [
        ...params,
        'savedValue='+ await getSavedValue()
      ];
    }
    params = params.join('&');
    console.log(params);
    return Api.get(`/posts/5132?${params}`).then(resp => {
      console.log(resp.posts);
      dispatch(setFetchedPosts({ post: resp.posts }));
    }).catch( (ex) => {
      console.log(ex);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working. Crashes with error "Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'. This error usually comes when await is used without async.

Comment: adding `async` to `fetchData` means that `fetchData` will return a Promise and you can use async inside `fetchData` .... the problem is, the `await` is added to the function returned by calling `fetchData` ... perhaps `return async (dispatch, getState) => {` would help

Comment: @KetanMalhotra I have edited it, earlier i put the `async` in wrong position. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Adding `async` to `return (dispatch, getState) => {` so you can await in it

```
import {getSavedValue} from '../lib/ValueHandler';
import Api from '../lib/Api';

export function fetchData() {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        let params = [
            'client_id=1234567890',
        ];
        const val = await getSavedValue();
        if (val != null) {
            params = [...params, 'savedValue='+val];
    // why not 
    //      params.push(`savedValue=${val}`);
    //
        }
        params = params.join('&');
        return Api.get(`/posts/5132?${params}`))
        .then(resp => {
                dispatch(setFetchedPosts({ post: resp.posts }));
        })
        .catch( (ex) => {
            console.log(ex);
        });
    };
}
```